# cross domain ajax requests

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, post, request

Cross domain ajax requests are denied, but I can around it by this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var data = ...;
  $('<img>').attr('src', 'http://domain.com?data=' + escape(data)).appendTo('body');
});
```

So if I really want I can **send** data to another domain. Also I can **get** data the same way, but on load I can for example move it on canvas and then read pixels.

So what is the point in this restriction and what it can save from?

Comment: Servers can reject GET requests to URLs that make updates, in other words requiring that the requests be POST requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what is the point in this restriction and what it can save from?

The point is to prevent your site from **reading** data from a remote site, not to prevent it sending data.

For example, you can't make my browser go to my bank and fetch my account details so you can send them to your webserver.

The same origin policy wouldn't prevent you submitting a request that money be transfered to your server, but that is why sites have to implement defences against [CSRF attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Comment: +1 because maybe you better understood OP's problem than me.

Answer (score 3):

You still can't read in javascript the pixels of your image when it comes from another domain. So you didn't go around anything.

A page can't manipulate or even read something coming from another domain without the collaboration of the server. This protects the user from many manipulations (google XSS attacks).

Comment: No, you can't. Try it : your javascript can't analyze an image coming from another domain.

Comment: Send with a script on your domain data coming from the other domain ? Maybe your question isn't clear : what are you trying to do that isn't explicitely allowed ?

Comment: You didn't demonstrate you can send to your domain data coming from the other domain that isn't explicitly allowed.

Comment: There's no protection against that and there is no reason to have one. The other domain will do what it wants with those data without security breach. Read the other answer from Quentin.